# Matching both possible solutions in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `aaab`. I want a Python expression to match `aa`, so I expect the regular expression to return `aa` and `aa` since there are two ways to find substrings of `aa`.

However, this is not what's happening.

THis is what I've done

```
a = "aaab"
b = re.match('aa', a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a look-ahead and a capturing group inside it:

```
(?=(a{2}))
```

Since a look-ahead does not move on to the next position in string, we can scan the same text many times thus enabling overlapping matches.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM8rR7/1)

[Python code](http://ideone.com/46XBk2):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?=(a{2}))')
test_str = "aaab"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm trying to generalize it to substrings of any amount of characters. I tried `(r'(?=(a{*}))')` but that gets me an array of `[]`

Comment: Hmmm... so I played more and figured out to use `a*` (without the curly brackets) but now it gives me: `['aaa', 'aa', 'a', '', '']`. I'm expecting `['aaa', 'aa', 'aa', 'a', 'a', 'a', '', '']`

Answer (score 0):

To generalize @stribizhev solution to match one or more of character `a`: `(?=(a{1,}))`

For three or more: `(?=(a{3,}))` etc.

Comment: dang I can't upvote because I don't have enough rep. But I would if I could